# how to show all the siamese twins with diference 1 in discrete mathematics

Tags: discrete-mathematics

two prime numbers p and q are siamese twins if |p-q|= 1. List all the
siamese twins that exist, and prove your list is complete.

i have found a  siamese twin, 2 and 3 but how do i prove it is the list of all the 
siamese twins with difference one?

pliz explain the answer as i am still a undergraduate student year 1.

Comment: All prime numbers greater or equal to $3$ are odd numbers. Therefore their distance is at least $2$. Hence the only siamese twins are $2$ and $3$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, take a look at the first few prime numbers; 2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, ...
Now, notice that 2 is the only even prime number, because every even integer is written in the form 2a, where a is some integer. That is, all prime numbers other than 2 are odd. Then you can see that no two primes can be consecutive integers other than 2 and 3, since the rest of the primes have to be two consecutive odd integers.